# Does a local symmetry transformation cause a change in kinetic energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism

Consider a local transformation

$$ \varphi_i^{\prime}= \varphi_i + \alpha(x) \delta\varphi $$

If this is a symmetry of the action, the Lagrangian is given by

$$ \mathcal{L}^{\prime}=\mathcal{L}+ j^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \alpha(x) $$

where $j^{\mu}$ is the Noether current corresponding to the field transformation with $\alpha(x)$ constant.

We now have a different Lagrangian (density) than before the transformation. Since the Lagrangian is the kinetic energy minus potential energy, and $\delta \mathcal{L}$ features a derivative, it seems that such a transformation gives rise to a change in kinetic energy. Is this indeed the case? Are local symmetry transformations generally associated with an increase in kinetic energy?

Comment: Kinetic energy of what?

Comment: Kinetic energy of the field configuration of $\varphi_i$, I guess.